# Is it Worth to Spread Close-Votes on 1+ Year Questions?

Tags: discussion, support

While editing older questions (one year+) from time to time, I also place close-votes on some.

Is it worth? Or is it just totally useless because of the age of the question?

Comment: Why would it be worthless? If anything, it would help prevent argumentation along the lines of "why did my recent question get closed when this old one is apparently perfectly fine?".

Comment: @Bart: That's why I'm asking.

Comment: I know. I'm just wondering what motivated the question. Why you would ever think it might be useless.

Comment: Well it could be useless because the question is old and close-votes should be put on newer questions because there they have more power. (I actually just make that argument off the head, so don't stretch it too much). Also I didn't wrote that I actually believe they are useless. I'm asking. Just plain dialectics, it's an easy way to get feedback.

Answer (score 14):

At the very least, the question will be placed in the [Close Votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/) review queue, so it's not a waste.  (I know there are 50k questions in there right now, but we'll clear that thing eventually.)

Comment: Please place some Badges on that queue that can be awarded multiple times. Like "**Closer (Bronze)** - You helped to close successfully 100 questions.", then 500 for silver and for Gold 1000 and gold badge can be achieved multiple times ;)

Comment: @hakre There are already badges for reviews.  For example, Custodian.

Comment: Yes I know, but those for close-votes, there must be more incentive. That que is flooded, other queues are empty.

Comment: @hakre - see other meta question -giving badges does not seem to produce quality closes - easiest to get badges by just  vote to leave open each question  rather than read it and think

Comment: @Mark: Yes, that can be true. I see that for the reviews of new questions and answers. The reviews are of fascinating bad quality.

Answer (score 11):

If the question should be closed, vote to close it. Don't worry about what happens after that. :-)

If you've edited the question, it'll show up on the active list, and so people may see it and agree with you. Or they may not. Close-votes on questions have no negative effect except on the question (and questioner's rep, if it gets closed as NARQ or OT resulting in a Community downvote, or you also downvote it), so...

Comment: Yes, I normally don't treat the older questions differently to the new ones.

Comment: How does a close vote affect the questioner's rep? I know that it contributes to question ban heuristics but I'm not sure how it contributes to reputation directly. Indirectly, perhaps, as people who vote to close may also down-vote, or people may down-vote when they see that someone else has close-voted...

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Sorry, I conflated two things there. I'm talking about the [downvote cost](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation), not the close vote cost. I meant to talk about both and sort of over-condensed. :-) Thanks for flagging it up.

Comment: @AaronBertrand IIRC, closing a question as NARQ or OT gives an automatic Community downvote. So a close vote is a potential -0.4 to the OP's rep.

Comment: @DanielFischer Isn't that a -2?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I suspect Daniel meant -0.4 because closing a question requires five close votes. So one close vote is (potentially) -0.4 (-2 / 5). It was subtle. :-)

Comment: @kiamlaluno I can confirm T.J. Crowder's suspicion.